# How to figure out hdfs URI - java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How can I figure out the URI my `hdfs dfs` commands are connecting to?

Is there any configuration file that stores the URI or any command that can be used to display it?

I looked into the documention of [FileSystemShell](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html) and the [dfsadmin documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#dfsadmin) without success. (Also, I do not have access to most of dfsadmin commands.)

When I call a command with `hdfs:///user/myUserName/...` it throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///user/myUserName/test.avro
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
        at org.apache.avro.mapred.FsInput.<init>(FsInput.java:38)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.Util.openSeekableFromFS(Util.java:110)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileGetSchemaTool.run(DataFileGetSchemaTool.java:47)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:87)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

Simple commands like `hdfs dfs -ls` are working fine.

Using Hadoop 3.1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're able to access the file `core-site.xml`, then you can look for the value assigned to property `fs.defaultFS`

```
$ grep -A 2 defaultFS /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://bigdataserver-2.internal.cloudapp.net:8020</value>
  </property>
```

Note: I use Cloudera and `core-site.xml` is where i get the detail. For Hadoop, you might be having `core-default.xml`

Check this out: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.5/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml

Comment: `core-default` would typically always be `file:///`. It is always recommended to set `defaultFS` is `core-site`